# Clickhouse. Create table from exist mysql DB

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

It is necessary to create a table based on the existing mysql database, but only with those records that have passed the WHERE check. I can simply create a table with records, but I cannot understand the logic of how to insert a block of WHERE checks. The official wiki simply says AS SELETECT 1. Sample code is provided below. Help me please.

```
"CREATE TABLE test_table (id UInt32, payment_date DateTime('Europe/Moscow')) 
 ENGINE = MySQL('{host}:{port}', '{database}', 'test_table', '{username}', '{password}')
 AS SELECT create_date FROM test_table
 WHERE create_date > '2020-01-01'";
```